# Application could not load requested class : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, mysql-connector

```
    Ιουν 10, 2020 2:57:56 ΜΜ org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}
    Ιουν 10, 2020 2:57:56 ΜΜ org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Ιουν 10, 2020 2:57:56 ΜΜ org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Ιουν 10, 2020 2:57:56 ΜΜ org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    Ιουν 10, 2020 2:57:56 ΜΜ 

    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
        at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:20)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
        ... 25 more
```

Anyone could help me with these errors? 
I am trying to write data on database through hibernate, I add the jar files to my project (Right click->properties->Libraries

I use *my-sql-coonector-java-5.1.49* and *hibernate 5.2*.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot but your stacktrace and the way you are adding dependencies is actually working against it.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html).

> The name of the class that implements `java.sql.Driver` in MySQL Connector/J has changed from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. The old class name has been deprecated.

It looks like you should use the old class name `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with `my-sql-coonector-java-5.1.49` or as a better alternative I would suggest to use a [8.0 version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) of mysql jdbc driver.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer!!

Comment: @EleniAgou There are better ways to say thanks. Just [pay it forward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) :)